# With Storyboards only, how do I create a UITableViewCell that can scroll left and right using UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

Similar to Mail.app where you can scroll the cells side to side, I want to be able to do it in my app using Storyboards and `UIScrollView` with my `UITableViewCell`.

I add some buttons to the `contentView` of my cell, and then `UIScrollView` with an embedded `UIView` on top of that to contain the main portion of the cell. I then add a label to that.

I understand that scroll views in Storyboard work by specifying constraints to show what the `contentSize` of the scroll view should be.

So I position the `UIView` in the `UIScrollView` to be the same width and height of the scroll view, but give it a trailing constraint of say 50pt to allow the scroll view to scroll. When I run it I can then move the cell to the left to reveal the buttons.

But to get it work in the other direction I have no idea. If I add a leading constraint it actually moves the cell to begin with away from the left, offsetting the cell to begin with when it should be left to the user to scroll it. It works fine other than initially being pushed over.

I created a sample project showing it here: http://cl.ly/2i3m1W2T0i3C

Like I said I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to scroll in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the contentView of the scrollView with width higher than the scrollView itself.
Something like:

Assuming your scrollView.frame is (0,0,100,100)

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300,100)];
```

Comment: How would I do this in conjunction with the Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

place your table view, let a part of your view out of the screen and check that case:

[image]